# Show that $R_3(k) > \frac{k}{3e} \sqrt {3}^k$ and $R_r(3) > 2^r$ .

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, ramsey-theory

I read that the interesting identity $R_3(k) > \frac{k}{3e} \sqrt {3}^k$ and $R_r(3) > 2^r$ holds (where R stands for the Ramsey numbers) but no proof was given. I'm not sure how to go about the proof. How is this done?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It's clear in the question..